# Groupon API not returning category to related deal

Tags: api, groupon

I am working on groupon deals API to show  deals on my website, I am getting all the results which API returns, but it is not giving me any category to related deal. I want a categories to categorized the deals.

Any idea to get categories from groupon ? I am coping one result for better understanding.

```
{
"deals": [
    {
        "type": "groupon",
        "tippingPoint": 0,
        "isOptionListComplete": true,
        "division": {
            "lng": -99.7331,
            "timezone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
            "lat": 32.4487,
            "timezoneIdentifier": "America/Chicago",
            "name": "Abilene, TX",
            "id": "abilene",
            "timezoneOffsetInSeconds": -21600
        },
        "announcementTitle": "Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double Crystal Ball Earrings",
        "allowedInCart": true,
        "isTipped": true,
        "dealUrl": "http://tracking.groupon.com/r?tsToken=US_AFF_0_201236_212556_0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.groupon.com%2Fdeals%2Fgg-sterling-silver-swarovski-elements-double-crystal-ball-earrings%3Fz%3Dskip%26utm_medium%3Dafl%26utm_source%3DGPN%26utm_campaign%3D201236%26mediaId%3D212556",
        "areas": [],
        "status": "open",
        "soldQuantity": 50,
        "pitchHtml": "<p></p>\n\n<h4>Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double Crystal Ball Earrings</h4>\n\n<ul>\n  <li>Unique double-ball earrings</li>\n  <li>Genuine Swarovski Elements crystals</li>\n  <li>.925 sterling silver</li>\n  <li>Nickel- and lead-free</li>\n  <li>6mm ball on top, 10mm ball on bottom</li>\n  <li>Butterfly post backs</li>\n  <li>Overall dimensions: 17mm x 10mm x 0.1mm</li>\n</ul>\n\n<hr />\n\n<p><i>For questions pertaining to this deal, click the Ask a Question button below. For post-purchase inquiries, please contact <a href=\"http://gr.pn/zmfvIT\">Groupon customer support</a>.\n<br /><br />\nGoods sold by Groupon Goods. View the <a href=\"http://gr.pn/1gH6Dm7\">Groupon Goods FAQ</a> to learn more.\n</i></p>",
        "accessType": "featured",
        "grid6ImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/oqUZuNtSqpmnaX88v3bx/B2-4200x2544/v1/t460x279.jpg",
        "says": null,
        "isTravelBookableDeal": false,
        "sidebarImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/oqUZuNtSqpmnaX88v3bx/B2-4200x2544/v1/t200x300.jpg",
        "displayOptions": [
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "name": "timer"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "name": "quantity"
            },
            {
                "enabled": true,
                "name": "discount"
            },
            {
                "value": "goods",
                "name": "merchandisingType"
            }
        ],
        "placementPriority": "nearby",
        "isAutoRefundEnabled": false,
        "title": "Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double Crystal Ball Earrings",
        "shippingAddressRequired": true,
        "finePrint": "Limit 3 per person, May buy 2 more as gifts. <b>Free returns.</b> Does not ship to AK/HI/Canada/Puerto Rico.Most orders are delivered within 12 business days from the purchase date Does not ship to PO boxes <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/wqDomX\">See return policy.</a> <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/hqEozV\">Must pay applicable tax and provide name and shipping address at checkout, which will be shared to facilitate shipping.</a>  Goods sold by Groupon Goods.",
        "channels": [
            {
                "name": "Goods",
                "id": "goods"
            }
        ],
        "placeholderUrl": "https://secure-assets.grouponcdn.com/images/groupon/grayPlaceholder.png",
        "tippedAt": "2015-02-24T06:00:34Z",
        "vip": "",
        "soldQuantityMessage": "50+",
        "redemptionLocation": null,
        "merchant": {
            "websiteUrl": "",
            "facebookUrl": null,
            "twitterUrl": null,
            "uuid": "d8389750-664e-11e2-beb6-00259060b5bc",
            "ratings": [],
            "name": "Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double Crystal Ball Earrings",
            "id": "golden-moon-inc"
        },
        "isMerchandisingDeal": true,
        "dealTypes": [
            {
                "description": "For those who dress to thrill",
                "name": "Threads",
                "id": "wearables"
            }
        ],
        "shortAnnouncementTitle": "Swarovski Elements Ball Earrings",
        "largeImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/oqUZuNtSqpmnaX88v3bx/B2-4200x2544/v1/t440x300.jpg",
        "uuid": "7e831c0a-554e-43ea-a47d-d8e1ba4bf776",
        "textAd": {
            "headline": "",
            "line2": "",
            "line1": ""
        },
        "startAt": "2015-02-24T06:00:00Z",
        "isGliveInventoryDeal": false,
        "grouponRating": null,
        "smallImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/oqUZuNtSqpmnaX88v3bx/B2-4200x2544/v1/t50x50.jpg",
        "isInviteOnly": false,
        "locationNote": "",
        "tags": [
            {
                "name": "Shopping"
            }
        ],
        "limitedQuantityRemaining": null,
        "highlightsHtml": "<p>Double-studded earrings, with a 6mm ball and 10mm ball, draw onlookers&#8217; eyes with the impressive sparkle of Swarovski Elements crystals</p>",
        "endAt": "2015-03-10T04:59:59Z",
        "grid4ImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/oqUZuNtSqpmnaX88v3bx/B2-4200x2544/v1/t300x182.jpg",
        "id": "gg-sterling-silver-swarovski-elements-double-crystal-ball-earrings",
        "fulfillmentMethod": "Drop ship (Supplier small parcel)",
        "salesforceLink": "https://login.salesforce.com/006C000000wDIhdIAG",
        "options": [
            {
                "traits": [
                    {
                        "name": "Stone",
                        "value": "Lt Amethyst"
                    }
                ],
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "expiresInDays": null,
                "customFields": [],
                "status": "open",
                "soldQuantity": 1,
                "externalUrl": null,
                "maximumPurchaseQuantity": 5,
                "discountPercent": 88,
                "value": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$125.00",
                    "amount": 12500
                },
                "price": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$14.99",
                    "amount": 1499
                },
                "initialQuantity": 0,
                "buyUrl": "https://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-sterling-silver-swarovski-elements-double-crystal-ball-earrings/confirmation?pledge_id=12601090",
                "title": "Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double-Studded Earrings-Lt Amethyst",
                "minimumPurchaseQuantity": 1,
                "expiresAt": null,
                "uuid": "0717d2b9-178e-45df-9453-d2e1eaba433b",
                "soldQuantityMessage": "1",
                "discount": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$110.01",
                    "amount": 11001
                },
                "details": [
                    {
                        "description": "Limit 3 per person, May buy 2 more as gifts. <b>Free returns.</b> Does not ship to AK/HI/Canada/Puerto Rico.Most orders are delivered within 12 business days from the purchase date Does not ship to PO boxes <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/wqDomX\">See return policy.</a> <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/hqEozV\">Must pay applicable tax and provide name and shipping address at checkout, which will be shared to facilitate shipping.</a>  Goods sold by Groupon Goods."
                    }
                ],
                "bookable": false,
                "isLimitedQuantity": true,
                "redemptionLocations": [],
                "endAt": "2015-03-10T04:59:59Z",
                "id": 12601090,
                "specificAttributes": {},
                "isSoldOut": false
            },
            {
                "traits": [
                    {
                        "name": "Stone",
                        "value": "Light Rose"
                    }
                ],
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "expiresInDays": null,
                "customFields": [],
                "status": "open",
                "soldQuantity": 4,
                "externalUrl": null,
                "maximumPurchaseQuantity": 5,
                "discountPercent": 88,
                "value": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$125.00",
                    "amount": 12500
                },
                "price": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$14.99",
                    "amount": 1499
                },
                "initialQuantity": 0,
                "buyUrl": "https://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-sterling-silver-swarovski-elements-double-crystal-ball-earrings/confirmation?pledge_id=12601089",
                "title": "Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double-Studded Earrings--Light Rose",
                "minimumPurchaseQuantity": 1,
                "expiresAt": null,
                "uuid": "cb1315f1-3c34-40c5-81fb-a4342edc6549",
                "soldQuantityMessage": "4",
                "discount": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$110.01",
                    "amount": 11001
                },
                "details": [
                    {
                        "description": "Limit 3 per person, May buy 2 more as gifts. <b>Free returns.</b> Does not ship to AK/HI/Canada/Puerto Rico.Most orders are delivered within 12 business days from the purchase date Does not ship to PO boxes <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/wqDomX\">See return policy.</a> <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/hqEozV\">Must pay applicable tax and provide name and shipping address at checkout, which will be shared to facilitate shipping.</a>  Goods sold by Groupon Goods."
                    }
                ],
                "bookable": false,
                "isLimitedQuantity": true,
                "redemptionLocations": [],
                "endAt": "2015-03-10T04:59:59Z",
                "id": 12601089,
                "specificAttributes": {},
                "isSoldOut": false
            },
            {
                "traits": [
                    {
                        "name": "Stone",
                        "value": "Jet"
                    }
                ],
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "expiresInDays": null,
                "customFields": [],
                "status": "open",
                "soldQuantity": 8,
                "externalUrl": null,
                "maximumPurchaseQuantity": 5,
                "discountPercent": 88,
                "value": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$125.00",
                    "amount": 12500
                },
                "price": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$14.99",
                    "amount": 1499
                },
                "initialQuantity": 0,
                "buyUrl": "https://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-sterling-silver-swarovski-elements-double-crystal-ball-earrings/confirmation?pledge_id=12601088",
                "title": "Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double-Studded Earrings-Jet",
                "minimumPurchaseQuantity": 1,
                "expiresAt": null,
                "uuid": "c539d338-20d7-4c2a-a3eb-a0cb11583914",
                "soldQuantityMessage": "8",
                "discount": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$110.01",
                    "amount": 11001
                },
                "details": [
                    {
                        "description": "Limit 3 per person, May buy 2 more as gifts. <b>Free returns.</b> Does not ship to AK/HI/Canada/Puerto Rico.Most orders are delivered within 12 business days from the purchase date Does not ship to PO boxes <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/wqDomX\">See return policy.</a> <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/hqEozV\">Must pay applicable tax and provide name and shipping address at checkout, which will be shared to facilitate shipping.</a>  Goods sold by Groupon Goods."
                    }
                ],
                "bookable": false,
                "isLimitedQuantity": true,
                "redemptionLocations": [],
                "endAt": "2015-03-10T04:59:59Z",
                "id": 12601088,
                "specificAttributes": {},
                "isSoldOut": false
            },
            {
                "traits": [
                    {
                        "name": "Stone",
                        "value": "Crystal AB"
                    }
                ],
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "expiresInDays": null,
                "customFields": [],
                "status": "open",
                "soldQuantity": 3,
                "externalUrl": null,
                "maximumPurchaseQuantity": 5,
                "discountPercent": 88,
                "value": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$125.00",
                    "amount": 12500
                },
                "price": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$14.99",
                    "amount": 1499
                },
                "initialQuantity": 0,
                "buyUrl": "https://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-sterling-silver-swarovski-elements-double-crystal-ball-earrings/confirmation?pledge_id=12601087",
                "title": "Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double-Studded Earrings-Crystal AB",
                "minimumPurchaseQuantity": 1,
                "expiresAt": null,
                "uuid": "58fcb76c-17c5-40af-8303-7eb1c65171d0",
                "soldQuantityMessage": "3",
                "discount": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$110.01",
                    "amount": 11001
                },
                "details": [
                    {
                        "description": "Limit 3 per person, May buy 2 more as gifts. <b>Free returns.</b> Does not ship to AK/HI/Canada/Puerto Rico.Most orders are delivered within 12 business days from the purchase date Does not ship to PO boxes <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/wqDomX\">See return policy.</a> <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/hqEozV\">Must pay applicable tax and provide name and shipping address at checkout, which will be shared to facilitate shipping.</a>  Goods sold by Groupon Goods."
                    }
                ],
                "bookable": false,
                "isLimitedQuantity": true,
                "redemptionLocations": [],
                "endAt": "2015-03-10T04:59:59Z",
                "id": 12601087,
                "specificAttributes": {},
                "isSoldOut": false
            },
            {
                "traits": [
                    {
                        "name": "Stone",
                        "value": "Crystal"
                    }
                ],
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "expiresInDays": null,
                "customFields": [],
                "status": "open",
                "soldQuantity": 30,
                "externalUrl": null,
                "maximumPurchaseQuantity": 5,
                "discountPercent": 88,
                "value": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$125.00",
                    "amount": 12500
                },
                "price": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$14.99",
                    "amount": 1499
                },
                "initialQuantity": 0,
                "buyUrl": "https://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-sterling-silver-swarovski-elements-double-crystal-ball-earrings/confirmation?pledge_id=12601086",
                "title": "Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double-Studded Earrings-Crystal",
                "minimumPurchaseQuantity": 1,
                "expiresAt": null,
                "uuid": "7374ae5d-c2d5-4cf9-8ffa-cfb469217c72",
                "soldQuantityMessage": "30+",
                "discount": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$110.01",
                    "amount": 11001
                },
                "details": [
                    {
                        "description": "Limit 3 per person, May buy 2 more as gifts. <b>Free returns.</b> Does not ship to AK/HI/Canada/Puerto Rico.Most orders are delivered within 12 business days from the purchase date Does not ship to PO boxes <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/wqDomX\">See return policy.</a> <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/hqEozV\">Must pay applicable tax and provide name and shipping address at checkout, which will be shared to facilitate shipping.</a>  Goods sold by Groupon Goods."
                    }
                ],
                "bookable": false,
                "isLimitedQuantity": true,
                "redemptionLocations": [],
                "endAt": "2015-03-10T04:59:59Z",
                "id": 12601086,
                "specificAttributes": {},
                "isSoldOut": false
            },
            {
                "traits": [
                    {
                        "name": "Stone",
                        "value": "Light Peach"
                    }
                ],
                "remainingQuantity": 0,
                "expiresInDays": null,
                "customFields": [],
                "status": "open",
                "soldQuantity": 1,
                "externalUrl": null,
                "maximumPurchaseQuantity": 5,
                "discountPercent": 88,
                "value": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$125.00",
                    "amount": 12500
                },
                "price": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$14.99",
                    "amount": 1499
                },
                "initialQuantity": 0,
                "buyUrl": "https://www.groupon.com/deals/gg-sterling-silver-swarovski-elements-double-crystal-ball-earrings/confirmation?pledge_id=12601091",
                "title": "Sterling Silver Swarovski Elements Double-Studded Earrings-Light Peach",
                "minimumPurchaseQuantity": 1,
                "expiresAt": null,
                "uuid": "43cb8093-aecc-4664-a782-d18905d8377c",
                "soldQuantityMessage": "1",
                "discount": {
                    "currencyCode": "USD",
                    "formattedAmount": "$110.01",
                    "amount": 11001
                },
                "details": [
                    {
                        "description": "Limit 3 per person, May buy 2 more as gifts. <b>Free returns.</b> Does not ship to AK/HI/Canada/Puerto Rico.Most orders are delivered within 12 business days from the purchase date Does not ship to PO boxes <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/wqDomX\">See return policy.</a> <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://gr.pn/hqEozV\">Must pay applicable tax and provide name and shipping address at checkout, which will be shared to facilitate shipping.</a>  Goods sold by Groupon Goods."
                    }
                ],
                "bookable": false,
                "isLimitedQuantity": true,
                "redemptionLocations": [],
                "endAt": "2015-03-10T04:59:59Z",
                "id": 12601091,
                "specificAttributes": {},
                "isSoldOut": false
            }
        ],
        "isSoldOut": false,
        "isNowDeal": false,
        "mediumImageUrl": "https://img.grouponcdn.com/deal/oqUZuNtSqpmnaX88v3bx/B2-4200x2544/v1/t100x100.jpg"
    }
],
"facets": [],
"pagination": {
    "offset": 0,
    "count": 9886
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The only way to associate deals with a category is to cycle through the different categories provided in the documentation [here](https://partner-api.groupon.com/help/deal-api#dapi_categories).

So your URL must include the `filters=category:` parameter.

You can find example URLs at the link above.

Here are the categories at this time:

`automotive
beauty-and-spas
food-and-drink
health-and-fitness
home-improvement
local-services
shopping
things-to-do
auto-and-home-improvement
baby-kids-and-toys
collectibles
electronics
entertainment-and-media
food-and-drink-goods
health-and-beauty-goods
home-and-garden
household-essentials
jewelry-and-watches
men
sports-and-outdoors
women
accommodation
bed-and-breakfast-travel
cabin-travel
cruise-travel
hotels
resort-travel
tour-travel
vacation-rental-travel`

Note that not all countries support categories.